# Firebase console showing there was an error completing your request

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, firebase-console

I'm getting started with Firebase. As for Google there is just one email ID for all. So When I click on Go to Console it showing loading and then every time I'm getting this page:

[image]

Try again show the same. I understand it's a subjective question but it's been 20 minutes. The status of Firebase shows `Firebase is healthy!` What should I do?

Comment: Its happening to me too!

Comment: It is an outage. https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/17007

Comment: Its down for me to.

Answer (score 4):

Look here to view the status of all Firebase relates services: https://status.firebase.google.com/

As you can see, the Console is not available at this moment.

Comment: yes now it's showing `One or more Firebase services are down.` Can you please help me? I want want to know if firebase is good or not? Like the service is down right now and it's been hours here so the app I'll be running on it will be affected. What alternatives do you suggest for iOS?

Comment: My personal experience with the Firebase availability is very good. In the period I'm using it (more than 1 year), I have not yet experienced any downtime on the overall service. This was the first time I could not access the console, but this issue did not affect the service itself (I was able to use my Firebase app's without problems).

Comment: The issue was solved yesterday, but it still does not load the firebase console page. So that status update might not always be too accurate.